# How to iterate and check (using a function) elements in two lists and create a new list in the most efficient way?

Tags: python, list, iterator, nested-lists, processing-efficiency

This is the code: it's finding points x,y (on a table with rows 1,2,3,4,...n and columns 1,2,3,4,...4 where the table creates rows/columns) where the fraction x/y can be reduced, but all points surrounding it cannot, if GCD(x,y) == 1 it cannot be reduced.

```
    from math import gcd
    def numcalc (x,y):
    n1 = gcd((x-1),(y-1))
    n2 = gcd((x),(y-1))
    n3 = gcd((x+1),(y-1))
    n4 = gcd((x-1),y)
    n5 = gcd((x),y)
    n6 = gcd((x+1),y)
    n7 = gcd((x-1),(y+1))
    n8 = gcd((x),(y+1))
    n9 = gcd((x+1),(y+1))
    return n1,n2,n3,n4,n5,n6,n7,n8,n9

    n,listj = 1000,[]
    num1 = [i for i in range(2,n+1)]

    for x in num1:
        for y in num1:
            listi = numcalc(x, y)
            if listi[0]==listi[1]==listi[2]==listi[3]==listi[5]==listi[6]==listi[7]==listi[8]==1 and listi[4]!=1 and x<y:
                listj.append([x,y])
```

'''

I am just trying to make it faster so I can find a large number of x,y points (>100000).
I tried creating a nested list but this became:

```
listi = [[x,y] for x in num1 for y in num1 if numcalc(x,y)[0]==
         numcalc(x,y)[1]==numcalc(x,y)[2]==numcalc(x,y)[3]==
         numcalc(x,y)[5]==numcalc(x,y)[6]==numcalc(x,y)[7]==
         numcalc(x,y)[8]==1 and numcalc(x,y)[4]!=1 and x<y]
```

this was actually slower then before and I needed to call the funciton numcalc(x,y) multiple times which is what I think is slowing the code down. I'm wondering whether there's a way to create a list in the nested list so I tried this:

```
listj = [[x,y] for x in num1 for y in num1 if listi = numcalc(x, y)
         and listi[0]==listi[1]==listi[2]==listi[3]==listi[5]==
         listi[6]==listi[7]==listi[8]==1 and listi[4]!=1 and x<y]
```

But I get a syntax error :(

Does anyone have any ideas on how to make this code faster so I can iterate through lists of 100000 integers?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's good time to introduce `numba.njit`. It helps you to speed up your code exponentially, especially if your code heavily uses list,numpy, and math.

```
from math import gcd
from numba import njit

@njit(fastmath=True)
def numcalc (x,y):
    n1 = gcd((x-1),(y-1))
    n2 = gcd((x),(y-1))
    n3 = gcd((x+1),(y-1))
    n4 = gcd((x-1),y)
    n5 = gcd((x),y)
    n6 = gcd((x+1),y)
    n7 = gcd((x-1),(y+1))
    n8 = gcd((x),(y+1))
    n9 = gcd((x+1),(y+1))
    return n1,n2,n3,n4,n5,n6,n7,n8,n9


def append_list(n):
    listj = []
    num1 = [i for i in range(2,n+1)]

    for x in num1:
        for y in num1:
            listi = numcalc(x, y)
            if listi[0]==listi[1]==listi[2]==listi[3]==listi[5]==listi[6]==listi[7]==listi[8]==1 and listi[4]!=1 and x<y:
                listj.append([x,y])
    
    return listj

%timeit append_list(1000)
684 ms ± 22.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit append_list(10000)
```

Also, you can check out `product` and `count` from `itertools` to make your looping more efficient.

Comment: numba.njit seems to be to good to be true I'Il check out how to use it more often as well as product, count, and intertools, thanks for the help Kevin:)

Answer (score 0):

Use python's builtin map() function. See help(map)

```
from math import gcd
from time import time


def numcalc(x, y):
    n1 = gcd((x - 1), (y - 1))
    n2 = gcd((x), (y - 1))
    n3 = gcd((x + 1), (y - 1))
    n4 = gcd((x - 1), y)
    n5 = gcd((x), y)
    n6 = gcd((x + 1), y)
    n7 = gcd((x - 1), (y + 1))
    n8 = gcd((x), (y + 1))
    n9 = gcd((x + 1), (y + 1))
    return n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6, n7, n8, n9


n, listj = 1000, []
num1 = [i for i in range(2, n + 1)]
start = time()
for x in num1:
    for y in num1:
        listi = numcalc(x, y)
        if listi[0] == listi[1] == listi[2] == listi[3] == listi[5] == listi[
            6] == listi[7] == listi[8] == 1 and listi[4] != 1 and x < y:
            listj.append([x, y])
elapsed_time_first_approach = time() - start
listj_version_1 = listj[:]

# 2nd approach using map()
start = time()
numberator_denominator = []
for x in num1:
    for y in num1:
        # Create list of tuples
        numberator_denominator.append((x, y))
# Next process the tuples using the map function.
listi = list(map(numcalc, numberator_denominator[0],numberator_denominator[1]))
if listi[0] == listi[1] == listi[2] == listi[3] == listi[5] == listi[
    6] == listi[7] == listi[8] == 1 and listi[4] != 1 and x < y:
    listj.append([x, y])
listj_version_2 = listj[:]
elapsed_time_second_approach = time() - start
print(f'{elapsed_time_first_approach=}')
print(f'{elapsed_time_second_approach=}')
# The next line verified an new listj has been generated by each method
print(f'{listj_version_1 is listj_version_2=}')
# The next line verifies the listj generated by each method have the same contentss
print(f'{listj_version_1 == listj_version_2=}')
```

Verification

```
elapsed_time_first_approach=1.0969998836517334
elapsed_time_second_approach=0.10849332809448242
listj_version_1 is listj_version_2=False
listj_version_1 == listj_version_2=True
```

Comment: Thanks Carl, I heard about map() and couldn't work out how to use it for this code thanks for showing how to use it and illustrating how much faster it is wow!

Comment: @Greenboi1234, You are welcome. I would appreciate it if you would mark my answer as accepted.